# Is it possible to configure apache so it will retry (resend) requests to application if they fail?

Tags: apache2

We are running apache2 in front of numerous different applications. 
It is possible to configure apache2 so it will automatically re-try HTTP request is the request fails with some error (like 501 or something like that)?

BTW, we use Proxy and BalancerMember to forward requests.

Comment: Not sure about Apache, but [this is trivial with nginx](https://nginx.org/r/proxy_next_upstream).